# Having issues with a function returning a file pointer

Tags: c, function, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was hoping to get a hand a function and call to take in a text file as input use dynamic memory allocation and then return a file pointer, I am not getting any errors currently but I am not understanding how to return the full multiline pointer

```
    char * readFile ( char * filename){
    char text[5][100];
    int i=0;
    char ** input=NULL;
    input=malloc(sizeof(char*));
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen(filename,"r");
    while(!feof(fptr)){
    fgets(text[i],1000,fptr);
    i++;
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    for (int j = 0; j<i; j++){
    input[j]=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(text[j])+1);
    strcpy(input[j],text[j]);
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < i; a++){
    printf("%s",input[a]);
    }
    return *input;
    }
```

The call was just:

```
printf("%s", readFile("test1.txt"));
```

Comment: You want to return not a file pointer but a pointer to string, don't you?

Comment: yes sorry, never had to do that before

Comment: You need to free memory that you lose all access to — you have two calls to `malloc()` and you return at most a pointer to one of those.  You also leak the open file stream.  You have to consider not only how resources are allocated but also how they are freed.  Since you don't save the pointer returned, you can't free that, either.  So you leak 2 blocks of memory and one file stream in a single function call.  You really don't need `char **input = malloc(sizeof(char*));` (spread over one or two lines).  You can use `char *input = malloc(strlen(text) + 1); strcpy(input, text); return input;`.

Comment: You should check that the file is opened successfully and that the memory is allocated successfully too.  A lot of C programming is about error checking — boring, but oh so necessary.

Comment: thank you I have everything working the parameters but I am only reading the first line of the text file not sure how to address that

Answer (score 0):

To address the various problems spotted by MikeCAT and others:

1. Check the return value of `fopen` and take some appropriate action if `NULL`. One option is to return `NULL`.
2. Close the file before returning.
3. Check the return value of the `malloc` calls and take appropriate action, such as returning `NULL`.
4. The function allocates two blocks of memory, one to store a pointer and one to store the text. But it only returns the pointer to the block used to store the text. It ought to free the block used to store the pointer.
5. Really, there is no need to allocate a block to store the pointer at all. A simple variable will do. If you change `char **input;` to `char *input;` you can use `input` as the variable.

```
char * readFile ( char * filename){
    char text[500];
    char * input=NULL;
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen(filename,"r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    fgets(text,500,fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    input=malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(text)+1));
    if (input == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(input,text);

    return input;
}
```

The caller is responsible for freeing the memory returned by `readFile`. For example:

```
    char *contents;
    contents = readFile("test1.txt");
    if (contents == NULL) {
        /* Error */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%s", contents);
    /* Do something else with contents here if you want. */
    /* ... */
    /* Now free the memory. */
    free(contents);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Im only reading the first line of the file, last issue